# SQL Server auto update table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm currently using the SQL statement shown here to get all the distinct region data from `dbo.table0` but I would like to trigger auto insert/update on `dbo.table1(region)` when `dbo.table0` have new region insert into the column.

But I have no idea how to query it.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1(region) 
    SELECT DISTINCT region 
    FROM dbo.table0;
```

Comment: When you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) what did you get stuck on?

Comment: Hi @Dale K, if i put the above query in body of the trigger. Will it insert all distinct region data from dbo.table0 again into dbo.table1 or just only insert the new region data which is not exist in dbo.table1(region)

Comment: What do you want to happen where on `update`? Anything on `delete`?

Comment: Hi @HABO.@B.Muthamizhselvi had give me the solution. By the way, thanks guys for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below trigger

```
Create table table0 (region varchar(20))
Create table table1 (region varchar(20))

insert into table0 values ('Muslim'),('Christian'),('Hindu')

CREATE TRIGGER tg_Relegion ON table0
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.table1(region) 
    SELECT DISTINCT a.region FROM inserted a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b on a.region = b.region
    WHERE b.region IS NULL

END

insert into table0 values ('xx'),('Christian'),('Hindu')

select * from table1
```

Comment: Why did you `select` from `dbo.table0` rather than [`inserted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)? Checking _every_ `region` rather than the newly inserted ones seems inefficient.

Comment: Changed table name to Inserted instead of table0. thank you